# LinearLayout span after rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I have a `RecyclerView` using a `GridLayout`. The `RecyclerView` has heterogeneous layouts (I followed this guide [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView)) with the difference that I have only on top of the `recyclerView` a `textView` showing some data. It works fine but when I **rotate** the screen, and the `gridlayout` is set with two or more `spans`, the `textView` is shown on the `first span` only but I want that the `span` will take the entire width of the screen regardless the number of `spans`.

Should I use a `tableLayout` for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is set a custom `SpanSizeLookup` on your `GridLayoutManager`.

```
    final int numSpans = ...

    // Create a grid layout with numSpans columns
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, numSpans);

    // Create a custom SpanSizeLookup where the first item spans all columns
    layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            return position == 0 ? numSpans : 1;
        }
    });
```